# ajax() function when it include in a mysql_

Tags: php

I modify a php comment system. I want add it after every article witch are query from database.

Answer (score 0):

The "data" property of a $.ajax request is actually a json object. jQuery deals with serializing and getting the data to the server automatically.

You want to do:
data: { title: title, content: content }

On the PHP end:
$title = $_POST['title']
$content = $_POST['content']

http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.post.php